# Multicollinearity due to dummy variables

Tags: categorical-data, nonlinear-regression, multicollinearity, categorical-encoding

I have two variables say $X$ and $Y$. The correlation between $X$ and $Y$ is $-0.03$. I've a dummy variable which is one if a specific event (exogenous to the variation in $X$ and $Y$) happens (e.g. $d_t = 1_{\{t \in A\}} $, where $t$ is a particular observation). $d_t = 1$ 50% of the time.

I'm running a nonlinear regression similar to:

$$ Z_t = K_t^\rho + d_t ( \alpha X_t^\rho + \beta Y_t^\rho ) + (1 - d_t) (\gamma X_t^\rho)$$

where the coefficients to be estimated are $\rho, \alpha, \beta, \gamma$, and K is another exogenous variable. $t \in \{1,...,90.000\}$. My issue is that the correlation between $d_t \times X_t$ and $d_t \times Y_t$ is around $0.98$, and it is due to the many zeros created by the indicator function, as $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are not correlated. Is this an issue for identification and estimation of $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

***** EDIT *****

I checked the correlation across $X$ and $Y$ after subsetting this two variables for $d_t = 1$ and it turns out that the correlation is $-0.1713421$. Is this enough to claim identification?

Comment: One problem with multicollinearity with ,measured variables is that the effect of measurement errors becomes enlarged.  With indicator variables, supposedly without error, this becomes less of an issue. Of course, if some of the categorical values could be wrong, again this becomes an issue.

Comment: In my specific application measurement error is not really an issue. I'm more concerned with the correlation between X and Y when the indicator variable is 1.

Comment: Probably not an issue. Just estimate the model and look at confidence intervals! if they are too wide maybe there is a problem ...